# Need help to improve writing the jquery code

Tags: jquery

I am new to CSS and JQuery.
I have developed some page using Html,CSS and JQuery.

I have taken some div's tag to perform some action ,i have done the jquery code like this according to my different div's tag..

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.Mydata').click(function () {
        $('#submenu').show();
    });

    $('.Mydata').click(function () {
        $('#submenuline').show();
    });

    $('.Personaldata').click(function () {
        $('.Personaltable').show();
    });

    $('.Personaldata').click(function () {
        $('.FourthPage_mainClass').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#MyDataLink').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#Fourth_Page_Address_Information').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#Fourth_Page_Note_Information').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_table1').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline1').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline2').show();
    });
    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline3').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline4').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline5').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline6').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline7').show();
    });
    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline8').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_table1_downline1').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_table1_downline2').show();
    });


    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_table1_downline3').show();
    });
    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#Fourth_Page_Message').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#Fourth_Page_Message1').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#Fourth_Page_Message2').show();
    });


    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_address_table').show();
    });

    $('#address').click(function () {
        $('#fourth_page_last_button').show();
    });
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
    <div id="submenu">
         <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" id="submenubackgroundcolor"class="Personaldata"> Personal Data</a>  | 
     </div>
     <div id="submenuline">
        -----------------------------------------
      </div>

   <table border="2" id="thirdpageleftsidetable" name="lefttable" bgcolor="#408080"  class="Personaltable">
      <tr>  
            <td>
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Personal Identity  <br />  
    </div>

     <div id="MyDataLink">
                   <a href="secondpage.html" style="text-decoration:none" >My Data</a>
               ->  <a href="thirdpage.html" style="text-decoration:none">Personal                Data</a>-> Address
      </div>

      <div id="Fourth_Page_Address_Information">
           Address Information
      </div>

      <div id="Fourth_Page_Note_Information">
         <b>Note:</b>&nbsp;Non-India Employee Please <a href="#">Click Here</a>
      /div> 

     <div id="fourth_page_table1">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    </div>
    <div id="fourth_page_table1_leftline1">
         |
    </div>
```

Like the same i have taken 8 line so i have used 8 div's like fourth_page-table1-leftline2,3,4,5,6,7,8.

```
  <div id="fourth_page_table1_downline1">
---------
</div>
```

Like this 3 down line,downline2,downline3 .according to same another some div's i have taken.

And i have taken CSS and many div's tag for the above jquery function.
Everything is working fine,but what i  am trying to do is as i have many div's,so i have taken many jquery function,is there any way to reduce the above code.

What i am thinking is i am going for a longer process.
Is there any solution for this kind of problem ?

Comment: please share your html code

Comment: Yes, improve your html, group your elements somehow and you'll be able to select and manipulate them more generic.

Comment: You can use multiple lines of code inside `$('#address').click(function () { ... });`. Also you can use a class (let's say `.showme` instead of all those IDs and reduce everything to a single `$('.showme').show()`.

Comment: i have posted the jquery  and html code,please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to the elements to easily target them, and a data attribute that specifies what elements to open. For example your `Mydata` element that opens `#submenu` and `#submenuline`:

```
<div class="Opener Mydata" data-open="#submenu,#submenuline">
```

Then you can bind all the elements using the same handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.Opener').click(function () {
    $($(this).data('open')).show();
  });

});
```

Comment: Will u tell me where i should put these div code ,i have done like this but this code is not working  <div id="submenu" class="Opener Mydata" data-open="#submenu,#submenuline"> <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" id="submenubackgroundcolor"class="Personaldata"> Personal Data</a>  | </div> <div id="submenuline">
 ----------------------------------------     </div>,will u guide how to do this ?

Comment: @Cool: That looks like it should work. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8ULxt/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ID's and classes you can use data-* attributes for this specific problem.

```
<div data-target="#your-target-id">...</div>
<div data-target="#your-target-id2">...</div>
<div data-target="#your-target-id3">...</div>
<div data-target="#your-target-id4">...</div>
```

jQuery code can then be reduced to the following

```
$('[data-target]').on('click', function() {
   var targetId = $(this).data('target');
   $(targetId).show();
});
```

Comment: You can also add a class, but still the `data-target` is helpfull. No reason to downvote this answer since this is a **working** answer for his question...

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the target elements and loop over it.

```
var d = ["#MyDataLink", "#Fourth_Page_Address_Information"];
$.each(d, function(idx, item) {
    $("#address").click(function() {
      $(item).show();
    });
});
```

This will reduce the code for `#address`. You can do the same for other elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by merging the handlers for the same events:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.Mydata').click(function(){
          $('#submenu').show();
         $('#submenuline').show();
        });

      $('.Personaldata').click(function(){
        $('.Personaltable').show();
       $('.FourthPage_mainClass').show();
      });

     $('#address').click(function(){
       $('#MyDataLink').show();
       $('#Fourth_Page_Address_Information').show();
       $('#Fourth_Page_Note_Information').show();
        $('#fourth_page_table1').show();
      $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline1').show();
      $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline2').show();
      $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline3').show();
      $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline4').show();
      $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline5').show();
      $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline6').show();
      $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline7').show();
      $('#fourth_page_table1_leftline8').show();
        $('#fourth_page_table1_downline1').show();
       $('#fourth_page_table1_downline2').show();
        $('#fourth_page_table1_downline3').show();
       $('#Fourth_Page_Message').show();
       $('#Fourth_Page_Message1').show();
       $('#Fourth_Page_Message2').show();
       $('#fourth_page_address_table').show();
      $('#fourth_page_last_button').show();
     });
   });
```

Then you could group the elements that act together either by wrapping them in a container element ( for instance), or by giving them a common class, and use a reference to the container or to the class to show and hide the elements.

Answer (score -1):

This is one easy refactor:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.Mydata').click(function () {
        $('#submenuline').show();
        $('#submenu').show();
    });

    $('.Personaldata').click(function () {
        $('.Personaltable').show();
        $('.FourthPage_mainClass').show();
    });

    var things = [
        '#MyDataLink',
        '#Fourth_Page_Address_Information',
        '#Fourth_Page_Note_Information',
        '#fourth_page_table1',
        '#fourth_page_table1_leftline1',
        '#fourth_page_table1_leftline2',
        '#fourth_page_table1_leftline3',
        '#fourth_page_table1_leftline4',
        '#fourth_page_table1_leftline5',
        '#fourth_page_table1_leftline6',
        '#fourth_page_table1_leftline7',
        '#fourth_page_table1_leftline8',
        '#fourth_page_table1_downline1',
        '#fourth_page_table1_downline2',
        '#fourth_page_table1_downline3',
        '#Fourth_Page_Message',
        '#Fourth_Page_Message1',
        '#Fourth_Page_Message2',
        '#fourth_page_address_table',
        '#fourth_page_last_button'
    ]

    $('#address').click(function () {
        for (x in things) {
            $(things[x]).show();
        }
    });

});
```